# Silently install multiple exe installers in one folder in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've been learning powershell just for a bit and i was wondering if let's say for example in "D:\installers" folder where i have let's say 15 installers(all inno Setup) it would be possible to run a silent install of all of those exes?

So far i've learnt how to run just one installer on silent which works perfectly fine. I just dont know how i would do it with multiple exes

`Start-Process -Wait -FilePath 'D:\Installers\Installer.exe' -ArgumentList '/silent' -PassThru` just for one installer

Comment: Please read the complete help for [about_foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-5.1) including the examples. That will get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$installers = get-childitem "D:\Installers"  -Filter "*Driver*.exe"
foreach($inst in $installers)
{
    Start-Process -Wait -FilePath ($inst.FullName) -ArgumentList '/silent' -PassThru
}
```

Get-Childitem can be used to get the installers, and with foreach you can go through the results

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you soo much!! Also one more thing. Would it be possible to apply something like: install exe silently from this folder that have only "Driver" in their name? I know it could probably be done with ``` | Where-Object Name -like '*Drivers*' | ``` right? But im not sure where to put it in the code or if it would actually work

Answer (score 0):

You may modify the path follow yours and copy it to powershell (ensure to run as administrator).
Powershell will run them in sequence one after another.

Start-Process -FilePath 'D:\Installers\Installer1.exe' -Wait

Start-Process -FilePath 'D:\Installers\Installer2.exe' -Wait

Start-Process -FilePath 'D:\Installers\Installer3.exe' -Wait